# NSString to NSDate conversion doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I have this method to convert my MySQL date to `NSDate` ... what am I doing wrong, the date comes out as `nil`?

```
- (NSDate *)dateFromMySQLString {
    if (self == nil) return nil;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"Y-m-d H:i:s"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:self];
    return date;
}
```

This is from a category on `NSString` and the value of self is `@"2014-02-12 09:03:44"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using PHP-style date format strings. This isn't what NSDateFormatter uses. [NSDateFormatter's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says:

> The format string uses the format patterns from the [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

I think the format pattern you're looking for is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. Replace your date format string with that one, and you should start getting the NSDate objects you want.

Answer (score 1):

Dates are coming nil because your **dateFormatter** is not right, you have to use this :

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Hope this helps you.